# Can't input text on edittext android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have problem with my android project. I used EditText in ScrollView but I can't input text on it? It run normally before I put data to spinner in java code. But now, even I comment java code, it still not work. Can you help me? Here is my code.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/booking_guest_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/mau_trang">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_booking_guest_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/booking_guest_info"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/caldroid_black"/>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/booking_drop_qd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_gray">
            </Spinner>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tv_passengername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/enter_passengername"
                android:background="@drawable/border_gray"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/booking_drop_baggages_tart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_gray">
            </Spinner>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/booking_drop_baggages_end"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_gray">
            </Spinner>
            </LinearLayout>
```

file .java

```
public class booking_form extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_qd, adapter_baggage_start, adapter_baggage_end;
    Spinner sp_qd, sp_baggage_start,sp_baggage_end;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.booking_form_activity);

        sp_qd = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.booking_drop_qd);
        sp_baggage_end = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.booking_drop_baggages_end);
        sp_baggage_start = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.booking_drop_baggages_tart);
        adapter_qd = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.nguoi_lon, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_baggage_start = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.baggage_start, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_baggage_end = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.baggage_end, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        //set các giá trị vào spinner
        sp_qd.setAdapter(adapter_qd);
        sp_baggage_start.setAdapter(adapter_baggage_start);
        sp_baggage_end.setAdapter(adapter_baggage_end);
    }

}
```

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to change EditText's

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```